# How do I gracefully disconnect MongoDB in Google Functions? Behavior of "normal" Cloud Run and "Functions Cloud Run" seems to be different

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, google-cloud-functions

In a normal Cloud Run something like the following seems to properly close a Mongoose/MongoDB connection.

```
const cleanup = async () => {
    await mongoose.disconnect()
    console.log('database | disconnected from db')
    process.exit()
}

const shutdownSignals = ['SIGTERM', 'SIGINT']
shutdownSignals.forEach((sig) => process.once(sig, cleanup))
```

But for a Cloud-Functions-managed Cloud Run this seems not to be the case. The instances shut down without waiting the usual 10s that "normal" Cloud Runs give after the `SIGTERM` is sent, so I never see the `database | disconnected from db`.

How would one go about this? I don't wanna create a connection for every single Cloud Functions call (*very* wasteful in my case).

Comment: instead of looping, have you try individually like
process.once(SIGTERM, cleanup), process.once(SIGINT, cleanup)

Comment: Yeah, I tried a dozen of different variations of the above until I arrived at the point where I'm pretty sure the problem is due to specific behavior of a "Cloud Functions Cloud Run".

Comment: As long as you are on Cloud Functions Gen 2, this should work. Are you sure the mongoose.disconnect() is not taking more than the supplied 10 seconds? Having a logging statement before that would verify that.

Comment: @cvu Yeah I tried logging more (and I said in general a dozen variations of the idea), and the logging only gets to the disconnect() and not further. I don't see any problems with the 10 second window with normal Cloud Runs, and disconnecting takes less than 1 second. I will look for other bugs in my code, but as of now I don't know of any other possible errors on my end.

Comment: The fact that it works on Cloud Run makes me think it's not related to your code. How big of a sample size are you looking at for when you tried on Gen 2 Cloud Functions? I know that that in some cases, the container will get killed immediately without SIGTERM if there are hard memory exceeds or other infra issues.

Other than that, I would suggest opening a support ticket if you don't see it happen at least in some cases for your Cloud Functions Gen2 app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is what I went with for now:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { Sema } from 'async-sema'

functions.cloudEvent('someCloudFunction', async (event) => {
    await connect()

    // actual computation here

    await disconnect()
})

const state = {
    num: 0,
    sema: new Sema(1),
}

export async function connect() {
    await state.sema.acquire()
    if (state.num === 0) {
        try {
            await mongoose.connect(MONGO_DB_URL)
        } catch (e) {
            process.exit(1)
        }
    }
    state.num += 1
    state.sema.release()
}

export async function disconnect() {
    await state.sema.acquire()
    state.num -= 1
    if (state.num === 0) {
        await mongoose.disconnect()
    }
    state.sema.release()
}
```

As one can see I used kind of a "reference counting" of the processes which want to use the connection, and ensured proper concurrency with `async-sema`.

I should note that this works well with the setup I have; I allow many concurrent requests to one of my Cloud Functions instances. In other cases this solution might not improve over just opening up (and closing) a connection every single time the function is called. But as stuff like https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-event-driven-functions#termination seems to imply, everything has to be handled inside the cloudEvent function.